# Embed media in Ckeditor field for drupal 7

Tags: nodes, files

I'm looking for a plugin for the latest version of CKeditor (3.6.3) so that I can add youtube videos (and other embedded media) to a text area that uses ckeditor.

I found several proposed plugins but most of them are not on the drupal.org site or are simply very old and do not seem to work with drupal 7.

There are a lot of questions on this subject but none that are recent or deal with drupal 7.

I know I can just turn off the rich editor and then embed the code in full html mode but I'd like something simpler for my client. Does such a module exist?

I've also found the media module (that is listed on drupal.org - http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) but I don't think it integrates with CKeditor.

To clarify I'm looking for something like this: http://www.fluidbyte.net/embed-youtube-vimeo-etc-into-ckeditor but that works with drupal 7. (This one doesn't seem to work?).

**EDIT**: I am using the standalone CKEditor module

Comment: A combination of Media, Media Youtube and [`Media Browser Plus`](http://drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) will provide that functionality pretty much out-of-the-box (with a small amount of configuration)

Comment: Thanks, I know that by using the media module I could do it but I would like to integrate it in the CKeditor module. So that my user can place it somewhere (anywhere) in a blog post. Adding an extra field would mean that I would have to style it to appear in a fixed position.

Comment: The media module has support for WYSIWYG, so as long as you're using that module (and not the standalone CKEditor module) it will do exactly what you've asked for

Comment: I am using the standalone CKEditor module, but perhaps it is worth giving the WYSIWYG module a try instead. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standalone version of ckeditor module comes with a plugin called media embed. Ensure you have:

- Enabled the media embed plugin for Ckeditor
- Added the media embed input filter to a text format that your uses have access to (and is not filtered or tag limited in anyway)
- Added the media embed button to the toolbar for the above text format

And that is it. In order to embed a youtube video (or anything for that matter), you get the `<iframe>` embed code from youtube, and paste it into the media embed dialog popup.

Comment: This works only with Ckeditor version 3. http://ckeditor.com/release/ckeditor-365. See more instructions here https://www.drupal.org/node/1882314

Answer (score 2):

There is different ways to go about this. The easiest way for you would be using [Ckeditor youtube](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ckeditoryoutube/).

You could also use the `<iframe>` solution, such as with the following markup.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-J3HfllvXWE" frameborder="0" width="547" height="333"></iframe>`
```

You can use the Media module; see [Post YouTube Videos with Media + Media: YouTube](http://drupal.org/node/1407140).

Comment: I already tried the CKeditor plugin and, being about a year and a half old, it doesn't seem to work with the latest version. The iframe solution could be a good option and one I overlooked so I'll keep that as my back-up. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6 and 7 you can use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_mediaembed which works with the media embed plugin, CKEditor and Wysiwyg module. (I am a co-maintainer and it seems to be working reasonably well for people)